# Aligning images on even/odd pages using fop

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

I need to align an image in the body of a page based on the page number: right align for odd pages, left for even pages. The images don't appear in the header/footer of the page but in the main content.

A search turned up an approach using repeatable-page-master-alternatives with simple-page-masters for even and odd pages. I figured I could pass a parameter to the template based on the even/odd page and use that to align the image.

This works great for headers and footers. But the solution uses multiple fo:flow blocks in a fo:page-sequence and fop (2.3) does not like that; it reports a

*For "fo:page-sequence", only one "fo:flow" may be declared.*

error.

```xml
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <fo:root>
      <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="recipes">          <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
            <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="recipes-odd" odd-or-even="odd"/>
            <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="recipes-even" odd-or-even="even"/>
          </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
        </fo:page-sequence-master>

        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="recipes-odd" page-height="{$height}" page-width="{$width}">
          <fo:region-body region-name="body-odd" margin="2cm"/>
          <fo:region-before region-name="before-odd" margin-top="0in" extent="3in" />
          <fo:region-after region-name="after-odd" extent=".5in" />
        </fo:simple-page-master>

        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="recipes-even" page-height="{$height}" page-width="{$width}">
          <fo:region-body region-name="body-even" margin="2cm"/>
          <fo:region-before region-name="before-even" margin-top="0in" extent="3in" />
          <fo:region-after region-name="after-even" extent=".5in" />
        </fo:simple-page-master>

      <xsl:apply-templates select="cookbook/*"/>
    </fo:root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="recipes">
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="recipes">
      <fo:static-content flow-name="before-odd">
        <fo:block></fo:block>
      </fo:static-content>
      <fo:static-content flow-name="before-even">
        <fo:block></fo:block>
      </fo:static-content>
      <fo:static-content flow-name="after-odd">
        <fo:block></fo:block>
      </fo:static-content>
      <fo:static-content flow-name="after-even">
        <fo:block></fo:block>
      </fo:static-content>
      <fo:flow flow-name="body-odd">
        <fo:block>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="recipe">
            <xsl:sort select="name"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="side" select="right"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </fo:block>
      </fo:flow>
      <fo:flow flow-name="body-even">
        <fo:block>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="recipe">
            <xsl:sort select="name"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="side" select="left"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </fo:block>
      </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
  </xsl:template>
```

Is there a way to get fop to handle multiple flows? If not, is there another approach to controlling the image alignment based on the page number?

Comment: If you were using a different formatter, XSL 1.1 allows `text-align="outside"`, which would solve your problem.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#text-align

Comment: Per FOP specs page, it only supports start, end, center and justify and hence there is no possible way to recognize left/right page alignment as inside or outside. see https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/compliance.html